# Which Paypal API/Method for simple PHP cart payment

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I know there are lots of other similar post asking similar questions to this (believe me - I've looked!) so I am sorry if this going over old ground, but I have not yet found a suitable answer.

I have quite a lot of PHP and HTML experience and have developed quite a few website payment systems. I usually use Sage Pay but as this particular customer is only going to do quite low volumes, they do not want a monthly fee - hence Paypal. I already have the customers details and their cart items etc so just need to process a one off payment for each order using cards or their Paypal account.

My problem is the bewildering mess of methods and APIs. There seems to be a ridiculous amount of 'Standards' and I nicely get settled on one when the documentation points me in another direction.

I have it currently set up using Paypal Payments Standard but I definitely don't like the unsecured form fields - I know I can use IPN to reconcile after but it just seems very unprofessional. I have yet to see a decent method of securing this (such as encryption, cURL or POSTing directly using PHP) but if anyone has one I would love to see it?

I seem to think that I should be using Express Checkout but then there are all the options like 'simple Payment Flow', 'Payflow Pro' etc!

So my question is

a) How can I secure Paypal Payments Standard? OR

b) Which other method/API should I be using?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry for rambling but I have been struggling with this for days.

Update:

Just to bring this up to date. I ended up using Stripe in the end, as per Machavity's suggestion. It is MUCH better than Paypal in every way! Easier, looks better and completely secure.

Comment: "I can use IPN to reconcile after but it just seems very unprofessional." why is that unprofessional? you should be doing it no matter what. a=  ssl

Comment: The full quote was: "I have it currently set up using Paypal Payments Standard but I definitely don't like the unsecured form fields - I know I can use IPN to reconcile after but it just seems very unprofessional" I was referring to the unsecured form fields as unprofessional, not reconciling with IPN.

Comment: well that's why a= ssl, that's how you get them secured and only the payment page really needs it, the over head means you shouldent just be securing all pges of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express Checkout is free to use regardless. It's not terribly hard to implement either. It would only work with Paypal account holders, however.

I'm partial to Website Payments Pro myself. It's easy to implement and there's several types of calls. It's one of the better APIs. As you said, however, it costs $30/mo. For low volume payments that doesn't work as well.

Have you considered [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)? They're more expensive than Paypal in the long run but they have no monthly fee. Might make more sense for your customer.

Comment: "It would only work with Paypal account holders, however." not true. you only need a cc you dont have to have a pp account

Comment: You're thinking of Payments Standard. If you use the API to get to Express Checkout you have to have a Paypal account.

Comment: I'll take your word for it :-) but i do believe that would make " Payments Standard" a better 'beginners' choice.

Comment: http://9seeds.com/tech/paypal-express-checkout-and-credit-cards/ thats enough research for me today ;-)

Comment: I originally ruled out Express Checkout because the information I had said that it was for Paypal Customers only but Dagon is correct and it can be used for cc payment too. This is exactly the problem I am having - all the documentation is contradictory and confusing!

Comment: I am currently looking into Stripe as they may well be better suited to my customer. If so I will be back later to mark this as answered by Machavity :-)